# Annoying encounters on the running track

Tags: riddle, wordplay

I was training at the track other day, and everyone I passed kept pestering me:

> "Hey, didn't I see you at Goodwill?"
>
> "Were you the guy from the start of the poker game last night?"
>
> "Can you stop it with the applause all the time? I needed to go
> straight home after the show, but the actors kept coming out to bow
> because of your ruckus!"
>
> "Thanks for replacing the bosun when he got sick! I know it's your
> job, but I still wanted to tell you that you did really well"

I had no idea what anyone was talking about - I'd spent the whole day here, running laps.

*Am I even going to qualify for the Olympic 400m dash at this rate?*

Hint:

> I was wearing a race bib with my name on it. Maybe these people were confusing me with someone because of my name.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think Lyra was *very* close in [their answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/119210/60644). In fact, I think they actually mentioned the solution phrase within their answer without necessarily realising... The character who is talking here is...

> ...the **second hand** on a clock! The running track in question isn't your typical outdoor athletics facility but a *clock face*, explaining how/why they'd "spent the whole day here, running laps" i.e. moving round the entire clock face (1 lap) every 60 seconds, all day long. 'Everyone [they] passed' implies the *minute hand* and *hour hand*, which travel more slowly.

Lyra has identified the relevant context for each of the shouted-out remarks, just not quite pushing the second, third and fourth to their full extent...

*"Hey, didn't I see you at Goodwill?"*

> As mentioned by Lyra, Goodwill is a US nonprofit organisation with thousands of thrift stores (charity shops) where you can buy things **second-hand** (i.e. used).

*"Were you the guy from the start of the poker game last night?"*

> The '**second hand**' is the round ('hand') immediately following the opening round in a poker game, i.e. which occurs very near the start of the game.

*"Can you stop it with the applause all the time? I needed to go straight home after the show, but the actors kept coming out to bow because of your ruckus!"*

> To give someone 'a big hand' means to applaud (like at the end of a theatre performance), so giving a performer a '**second hand**' might suggest you are applauding them repeatedly.

*"Thanks for replacing the bosun when he got sick! I know it's your job, but I still wanted to tell you that you did really well"*

> A 'hand' is also a crewmate on a ship, so a '**second hand**' (in the vein of a 'first/second mate' or 'first/second officer') might be someone who deputises for a more senior crewmate when required.

As for the question of whether this character will 'qualify for the Olympic 400m dash at this rate', here are two possible interpretations...

> 1. If it takes this character 60 seconds to perform 'a lap of their circuit' (i.e. to go around the clock face), this doesn't put them anywhere close to a professional 400m runner's lap-time on *their* track. At the Tokyo Summer Olympics in 2021, the *slowest* female runner in the heats clocked a time of 55.89 seconds and the slowest male 48.53 seconds. With this comparison the 60-second lap time of the second hand means they are very unlikely to qualify.
>
>  2. If instead we are merely to make deductions based on their name, then perhaps they might qualify but they are unlikely to win - after all, they will always be 'second'!

Comment: YES! That must be it! This solution acutally makes me love this riddle even more. Great solve, Stiv!

Comment: Brilliant solve to a very clever puzzle! :>

Comment: Exactly right! And for the record, my intended solution to the qualification question was the first of your two interpretations.

Answer (score 5):

Possibly a partial answer:

> Does your name, by any chance, look like the word *Hand*?

At Goodwill,

> one can buy things *second-hand*.

At poker,

> the set of playing cards a player has assambled is called a *hand*.

Applause

> is sometimes referred to as a *(big) hand*.

A bosun

> oversees the deck department on a ship and might possibly be replaced by a *deckhand*, if necessary.

Comment: Yes, it does! If you knew the rest of my name, would you know how fast I run?